# How to write clean asynchronous requests that can be called again

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, request, request-promise

I'm attempting to clean up my code with Promises and Async await. My problem is that I need these requests to be recallable with the same handling afterwards.

I've tried Promises, but if I nest everything in functions, it gets really messy fast. How do I make this code so that it only continues in the go() async function when a value is returned?

```
const request = require('request-promise');
require('console-stamp')(console, 'HH:MM:ss.l');
const colors = require('colors');
const kws = 'sweatsasaaser'.toLowerCase();
const size = 'Small';

go();

async function go(){
    const f = await getproduct()
    console.log('Finished ' + f)
    if (f == undefined) getproduct()
}

async function getproduct(){

    console.log('Requesting')
    let result = await request('https://www.supremenewyork.com/mobile_stock.json');
    let data = JSON.parse(result);
    let prodid;

    for (var i = 0; i < data.products_and_categories['Tops/Sweaters'].length; i++){

        if (data.products_and_categories['Tops/Sweaters'][i].name.toLowerCase().includes(kws)){
            console.info('Found product: '.green + data.products_and_categories['Tops/Sweaters'][i].name.green);
            return prodid = data.products_and_categories['Tops/Sweaters'][i].id;
        };
    };

    if (prodid == undefined){
        console.log(`Product id: ${prodid}`.blue);
        return prodid;
    }
    else {
        setTimeout(function(){
            //getproduct()
        }, 4000);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Write a separate function:

```
/** 
* Re-executes an async function n times or until it resolves
* @param {function} fn Function to call
* @param {number} [times=3] Times to retry before rejecting
* @param {number} [delay=1000] Delay between retries
* @param {number} [i=0] Counter for how many times it's already retried
*/
async function retry(fn, times = 3, delay = 1000, i = 0) {
  try {
    return await fn()
  } catch (error) {
    if (i < times) {
      await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, delay))
      return retry(fn, times, delay, i + 1)
    }
    else throw error;
  }
}
```

Have your main function `getproduct` simply throw the error

```
else {
    // setTimeout(function(){
    //     //getproduct()
    // }, 4000)
    throw new Error('Cannot get productid')
}
```

And use it with the new `retry` function:

```
async function go(){
  const f = await retry(getproduct, 3)
```

In case you wanna pass arguments, simply wrap it

```
const f = await retry(() => getproduct(...args), 3)
```